# Is there a way to make codeclimate ignore unmodified lines in PRs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-climate

We've just turned on CodeClimate for our PRs, and have a ton of refactoring to do, but it's making our PR's fail for lines of code that weren't touched.

i.e. if I modify anywhere in a file, it will analyze every line in said file.

Is there a way to stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Codeclimate is not able to detect changed code only.
This is one of the reasons I made my own linter:
https://gitlab.com/billyan2018/lite-linter